# NSView getting dragged events when dragging window

Tags: cocoa, nsview, nsevent, nsresponder

In my app there's the strange issue that a custom `NSView` receives **forwarded mouseDragged events** when the window is dragged around the screen, usually by its toolbar.

From the stack trace it seems that the Cocoa frameworks do this on their own.
(Probably the usual responder chain thing)

Now I'm trying to detect whether the dragged-event originated from my view or somewhere else - **is there any robust way of doing so?**

I couldn't find a public member that would store the view where the mouse-down occured (though `NSEvent` seems to store it internally in a private field).

Or any option to configure the window to not forward the dragged messages maybe?

Any hints appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`NSEvent` has [`locationInWindow`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSEvent/locationInWindow) which returns the location where the event happened as a `NSPoint`. Together with [`NSPointInRect`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/#//apple_ref/c/func/NSPointInRect) you could check if the location is in your window frame or similar.

Comment: That's what I'm doing already - converting the point in the event to view coordinated, checking against the view's frame - but it doesn't work at all times, e.g. when wildly dragging the window by its toolbar.